# How to adjust chrome cast's resolution on a TV

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I am trying to cast my Google Doc's ppt to a TV(using the "cast" option in chrome). The resolution of my computer is 16:9, while the TV's is 4:3. There is some black areas on TV screen. Is there anyway to overcome this?